# iterator find method for custom class vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I want to use find method of iterator to check if an instance of class I have defined already in the vector or not. I have overloaded the == operator for the class. However, I couldn't get it to compile.

What am I missing here?

Thanks n advance.

here is a snippet from the code:

```
vector<ContourEdgeIndexes>::iterator it = find(contourEdges.begin(),contourEdges.end(),contourEdgeCand);
        if(it != contourEdges.end()) {
            contourEdges.erase(it);
        }

compiler gives this error:
error: no matching function for call to     ‘find(std::vector<ContourEdgeIndexes>::iterator, std::vector<ContourEdgeIndexes>::iterator, ContourEdgeIndexes&)’

edit:
and here is the overloaded == operator:
bool operator == (ContourEdgeIndexes& rhs) {
    if((this->first == rhs.first) && (this->second == rhs.second))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the code snippet gives enough clue. Could you post code for `find` method?

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: When I include <algorithm> it complains about the operator overloading for ==

Comment: @bfaskiplar - since you haven't shown the `operator==` or the error message, it's not possible to say what's going wrong. Post a small snippet the **shows the problem**.

Comment: Its probably error in operator overload, rather then in algorithm header

Comment: @PeteBecker I have added operator== implementation

Comment: @bfaskiplar - what's the error message?

Comment: Your operator should take two `const` arguments. Yours takes 0 `const` arguments.

Comment: Your code is not const-correct. For example, if `operator==` is going to be a member function, it should be const. It should take a const reference. And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator should accept constant reference to `ContourEdgeIndexes`, if it defined as member. Also operator itself should be const.

```
bool operator == (const ContourEdgeIndexes& rhs) const {
    return ((this->first == rhs.first) && (this->second == rhs.second));
}
```

Comment: Missing a second const ;-)

Comment: @MarcGlisse, yes I was just fixing when you commented